# How to find "eigenmatrices "

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

On the space of 2 by 2 matrices, let $T$ be the transformation that transposes every matrix. Find the eigenvalues and "eigenmatrices" for

$A^T=eA$ where $e$ denotes the eigenvalue for the matrix.

Comment: "The" eigenvalue is ill-defined here. Are you missing an hypothesis?

Comment: I suggest beginning with a 2 by 2 matrix written as the usual $a,b;c,d$ but then writing that as a column vector with four entries, in order $a,b,c,d.$ Precisely what does the transpose operation on the matrix do to that vector with four entries? What 4 by 4 matrix accomplishes that, meaning $W$ is the 4 by 4 matrix, say $X$ is the column vector with four entries, and I am asking what $W$ needs to be to get $WX$ the desired outcome column vector?

Comment: Since the transpose of the transpose is the original matrix, $T^2 = I$ restricts the possible eigenvalues considerably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: the transpose operator squares to $1$. That means its eigenvalues must be $\pm 1$. Symmetric and antisymmetric matrices.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Representing a matrix
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\c&d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
as a vector (in the standard basis)
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b\\c\\d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The transpose operator acts as
$$
T(A)=
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\c\\b\\d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and it is represented by the matrix:

$$T=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now you can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assume $A$ is an eigenmatrix with eigenvalue $e$. Now look at the identity $(A^T)^T=A$. What information can we get about $e$ from this?

Answer (score 0):

$$ A = \frac{1}{2} (A+A^T) + \frac{1}{2} (A - A^T)$$
gives precisely the projection of a matrix $A$ onto the space of symmetric and anti-symmetric matrices having evals 1 and -1, respectively (so there is nothing else, as already mentioned elsewhere). Irrespective of what norm you put on the space.